# Is it possible that your password remains as it was earlier after going to the service center for unlocking

Tags: vivo

I have doubt that my phone has been unlocked by someone from its service center but when I saw my phone and I found the same lock which was earlier so I want to ask that is it possible that people at service center can recover the password after unlocking it?

Comment: It is a poor practice to hand over a device even for a minor repair without securing or erasing personal data.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not like that. It depends like if you are having an hardware problem ,they might wipe out your data and if are having an internal problem then they will wipe your data and then they will go through their procedures.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of service is performed? Many types of service can be done without unlocking the device, so they simply don't need to unlock. Most hardware repairs wouldn't require any unlocking, usually unlocking is only necessary for final testing (if there's any), which they might ask customer to unlock.

If unlocking is necessary during a particular repair and it requires multiple days to fix, usually the technician will ask customer to create a guest account or to remove the password before you hand the device over to them.